# Getting a use of package without selector error

Tags: go

I'm using this config library called [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper)

In my main I have this:

```
viper.SetConfigName("development")
viper.AddConfigPath("config/settings/")
err := viper.ReadInConfig()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("viper config read error %v", err)
}
```

I then have a struct that takes a viper as parameter:

```
type MyConfig struct {
  v *viper.Viper
}
```

In my main I have a function that returns this MyConfig like:

```
func NewMyConfig(v *viper.Viper) *MyConfig {
    return &MyConfig{v: v}
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
./main.go:55: use of package viper without selector
```

Not sure what I should be doing?

Comment: And what's in your `main.go` at line `55`?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7133 If one uses a package identifier without specifying an item in the package, the error
returned is "use of package foo not in selector"
(http://play.golang.org/p/Q-KDAvp9mN)

Comment: @icza line 55 is ```myConfig = NewMyConfig(&viper)```

Comment: @Blankman `&viper` => `viper` is the name of the package. You probably wanted `myConfig = NewMyConfig(viper.New())`. Or if you named your variable `viper`, change that.

Comment: @icza its wierd, I just imported the lib, and somehow I can use the variable ```viper```.  But in the code it creates a ```v``` in the init ? https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/master/viper.go#L42    I'm confused not sure what to do.

Comment: @Blankman `viper` is the identifier you can use to refer to the package. That `v` is an unexported variable of the package, you can't refer to that. You may use the package name to refer to the exported identifiers of the package, e.g. `viper.New()` to call the exported `New()` function which returns a pointer to a new, initialized `viper.Viper` struct.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When you [import](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) a package like

```
import "github.com/spf13/viper"
```

the package name (which is `viper` in this case) will be available to you as a new identifier. You may use this identifier to construct [qualified identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers) to refer to [exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) of the package (identifiers that start wtih an uppercase letter).

The package name itself cannot be used by itself. The line that gives you error:

```
myConfig = NewMyConfig(&viper)
```

You used package name `viper` without specifying what exported identifier you want to refer to from the package.

You want to use your `NewMyConfig()` function to obtain a pointer to a new value of your `MyConfig` struct. Your `NewMyConfig()` function expects a value of `*viper.Viper`. Since the `viper.Viper` struct contains unexported fields, you can just create it like `&viper.Viper{}`, but the `viper` package exports a function [`viper.New()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper#New) which can be used to obtain a pointer to a new, initialized `viper.Viper` value. You may use it like:

```
vp := viper.New()
myConfig = NewMyConfig(vp)
```

Note that the `viper` package declares an internal, global, unexported `viper.Viper` "instance". There are many exported *functions* that match *methods* of the `viper.Viper` type. These "matching" functions work on the global, unexported `viper.Viper` instance. So you may choose to use all the exported global functions of the `viper` package, or create your own `Viper` instance and then keep using its methods afterwards.

Comment: That is a mouth full to digest :P

Comment: gore: could not load 'fmt' package: err: go command required, not found: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH: stderr:

Comment: tl;dr Go basically doesn't support first-class anything and imports are no exception. Sigh.