# Use struct from different package golang

Tags: go, struct

I'm calling to object from current file which works
(i'm creating unit test)

```
type Requires struct {
    Name       string     `yaml:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

and I call it inside test like

```
Requires: []Requires{
{
    Name: "db",
}
```

**which works ok,**

Now I **move** the `Requires` struct to different package models

and I try to call it like

```
Requires: models.Requires{
{
    Name: "db",
}
```

> cannot use models.require as type `[]Require`

also tried with `models.[]Requires`

This give me the error

> use of package without selector error

[Getting a use of package without selector error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994445/getting-a-use-of-package-without-selector-error)

But not sure how to handle it for my case...

Any idea how to overcome this ?

**UPDATE**

When I try it like following

```
        Requires: models.Requires{
                Name: “db",

                },
            },
```

I got error

> cannot use models.Requires literal (type models.Requires) as type
>   []models.Requires in field value

This is the error from viscose

Answer (score 2):

The package is `models` which contains `Requires` struct used as slice. Have a look at [Qualified identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers) for more understanding of how package works.
In your case It needs a slice of `Requires` with `models` package, should be used as below:

```
Requires: []models.Requires{
{
    Name: "db",
}
```