# Why am I unable to use a struct defined in a different package?

Tags: go

I am unable to use a struct in `package main` which has been defined in a different package. Please note that I am importing the other package correctly

I named the struct and its fields starting with a capital letter because I read that in Golang that is how we indicate that it is an exported field. Although it is not required if the package is imported.

fsm.go

```
package fsm

import (
"fmt"
"strings"
 )
// EKey is a struct key used for storing the transition map.
type EKey struct {
// event is the name of the event that the keys refers to.
Event string

// src is the source from where the event can transition.
Src string
}
```

test.go

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"

"github.com/looplab/fsm"
) 
func main(){
    Transitions := make(map[EKey]string) 
}
```

`Error: undefined EKey`

Comment: While not recommended it is also possible to add a dot in front of the import, in which case *"all the package's exported identifiers declared in that package's package block will be declared in the importing source file's file block and must be accessed without a qualifier."* [read more here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)

Answer (score 8):

You have to first [import](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) the package whose [identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Identifiers) you want to refer to:

```
import "path/to/fsm"
```

Once you do this, the package name `fsm` becomes a new identifier in your [file block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks), and you can refer to its [exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) (identifiers that start with an uppercase letter) by using a [qualified identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers), which is `packagename.IdentifierName` like this:

```
Transitions := make(map[fsm.EKey]string)
```

See related question: [Getting a use of package without selector error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994445/getting-a-use-of-package-without-selector-error/36995058#36995058)

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to your struct using `fsm.EKey`

If you want to import it to your local name space, you need a dot before the import path.

```
import (
   // ....
   . "github.com/looplab/fsm"
)
```

Now you can refer to your struct directly as `EKey`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"

"github.com/looplab/fsm"
) 
func main(){
    Transitions := make(map[fsm.EKey]string) 
}
```