# Time type in Golang not recognized by compiler

Tags: go, struct, time

I'm trying to handle a struct in Go, which has two attributes that I need to be timestamps:

```
type Asset struct {
    Owner     string `json:"owner"`
    Key       string `json:"key"`
    StartDate Time   `json:"startDate"`
    EndDate   Time   `json:"endDate"`
    Type      string `json:"type"`
    Amount    int    `json:"amount"`
    Facility  string `json:"facility"`
    State     string `json:"state"`
}
```

I imported the "time" package, but the compiler gives me an error with the Time type:

> "undeclared name: Time compiler UndeclaredName"

Any tips on why this is happening?

Comment: You must qualify it. `time.Time`. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Time` type is defined in the [`time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package. You have to [import](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) that package:

```
import "time"
```

And use a [qualified identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers) to refer to the exported [`Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) type, which is `packagename.Identifier`, in this case `time.Time`:

```
type Asset struct {
    Owner     string    `json:"owner"`
    Key       string    `json:"key"`
    StartDate time.Time `json:"startDate"`
    EndDate   time.Time `json:"endDate"`
    Type      string    `json:"type"`
    Amount    int       `json:"amount"`
    Facility  string    `json:"facility"`
    State     string    `json:"state"`
}
```

Try the working code on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e4LusEVP79k).

See related: [Getting a use of package without selector error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994445/getting-a-use-of-package-without-selector-error/36995058#36995058)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `time.Time` when you define struct with timestamp.

Refer to https://golang.org/pkg/time/ and time struct https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=6278:7279#L117