# How to make array of regexp in golang

Tags: arrays, go

I'd like to filter out some paths from given regex patterns with the following code:

```golang
patterns := [...]string{`pattern1`, `pattern2`, `pattern3`, ...}
filters := make([]regexp, len(patterns))

for idx, pattern := range patterns {
  filters[idx] = regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
}

...
```

The above code couldn't be compile, and giving me **use of package regexp without selector** error, of cause I've import the package already, so, what is the correct way to make an array of regex? thanks.

Comment: See [Getting a use of package without selector error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994445/getting-a-use-of-package-without-selector-error)

Comment: regexp is a package, you are creating an array of packages not a data type. Regexp is the struct with capital R not regexp.

Comment: I've read the post already, but seems in differernt situation. The line produce the error is `filters := make([]regexp, len(patterns`, thiat is allocating storage for the regexp, not initializing the array element.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create an array of struct (a type) not an array of packages:

```
filters := make([]*regexp.Regexp, len(patterns))
```